# AWS-CDK error: There are no 'Public' subnets in this VPC. Use a different VPC subnet selection

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm porting my CDK stack from 0.30.0 to 0.39.0. I have a predefined VPC from my AWS account and I simply just import it to the stack. The same subnet works fine in 0.30.0, but I got an error message in 0.39.0:

"There are no 'Public' subnets in this VPC. Use a different VPC subnet selection."

I've a VPC and 3 subnets in my stack. I also have a gateway to dynamodb and s3.

Anyone has came across this problem?

I've tried to remove all other codes except importing the VPC.

In 0.30.0, I use these lines and there is no issue.

```
vpc = ec2.VpcNetwork.import(this, 'myvpc', {
  vpcId: 'vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  availabilityZones: ['ap-southeast-2a','ap-southeast-2b','ap-southeast-2c'],
  privateSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx']
});
```

In 0.39.0, I changed it to this:

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'myvpc', {
  vpcId: "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  availabilityZones: ['ap-southeast-2a','ap-southeast-2b','ap-southeast-2c'],
  privateSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx']
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I learned today that the cdk wants public subnets to be tagged. Seriously, even as of cdk 1.5.0 you need:

tag:  Key: `aws-cdk:subnet-type`  Value: `Public`

Comment: Upon which object do you add these tags?  You don't show any public subnets

Comment: @Jim Fondren how on earth did you find that out?? I still can't get it working though....

Comment: REF: https://twitter.com/pahudnet/status/1406945727520022529

Comment: See also answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624311/1021819

Answer (score 2):

I needed to specify what subnet to use during importing the vpc:

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "vpc", {
                vpcName: props.vpcName,
                isDefault: (!props.vpcName),
                subnetGroupNameTag: "Public subnet"
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved `Error: There are no 'Private' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Public` by changing the pertaining values in cdk.context.json from "Public" to "Private":

```
{
  ...
  "subnetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "Private",
      "type": "Private",
      ...
    }
  ...
}
```