# AWS CDK subnet selections

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I am working on AWS CDK to create load balancer. I am familiar with CloudFormation. During creation of Load Balancer I want to give subnets as below.

```
LB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Tags:
        -
          Key: "Name"
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      Subnets:
        -
          Fn::ImportValue: "infra-vpc-base::SubnetIdPrivateAz1"
        -
          Fn::ImportValue: "infra-vpc-base::SubnetIdPrivateAz2"
```

I tried to create LB in CDK as below.

```
lb = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
        self, "LB",
        load_balancer_name="Load Balancer CDK",
        vpc = vpc,
        internet_facing= False,
        security_group= mws_vpc_sg_alb,
        vpc_subnets= ???
    )
```

In the above code `vpc_subnets` I want to give two subnets. In the above code `vpc_subnets` is of type `typing.optional[aws_cdk.aws_ec2.SubnetSelection]= none`.

Can someone help me to get subnet selection in AWS CDK?

Answer (score 6):

Other way to find subnets in VPC - no need to hardcode IDs:

```
vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnets=vpc.select_subnets(subnet_name='Private').subnets
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

this is from an auto scaling group but should be the same:

```
vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType('PUBLIC'))
```

Comment: This works thanks but If  i want to pass subnets instead of subnettype then how can i pass?

Comment: For example If i want to pick individual subnets

Comment: try this: vpc.select_subnets(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC).subnets[0]

Comment: `subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC` ?

Answer (score 2):

Below code fixed my issue.

```
    subnetid1 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_attributes(self,'subnetid1', availability_zone = 'apse2-az1', subnet_id = 'subnet-9bb42fed')
    subnetid2 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_attributes(self,'subnetid2', availability_zone = 'apse2-az1', subnet_id = 'subnet-cfbfceab')
    vpc_subnets_selection = ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets = [subnetid1, subnetid2])


    #create application load balancer
    lb = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
        self, "MWSLoadBalancer",
        load_balancer_name="MerchWebServices Load Balancer CDK",
        vpc = vpc,
        internet_facing= False,
        security_group= mws_vpc_sg_alb,
        vpc_subnets= vpc_subnets_selection
    )
```

Comment: how did you manage to use SubnetSelection interface ?? When I am trying to use SubnetSelection interface, it is not visible. I get the compilation error -- Property 'SubnetSelection' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/sunnyarya/workspaces/aws-resource-provisioner/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/index")'

Comment: I faced the same problem on TypeScript, what i did was to simply instantiate SubnetSelection like this

{
...,
taskSubnets/vpcSubnets: {
  subnets: [yoursubnets]
}
}

Answer (score 2):

There is `from_subnet_id()` now:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as cdk_ec2


subnet_ids = ["subnet-firstsubnet", "subnet-secndsubnet"]
subnets = []
for idx, subnet_id in enumerate(subnet_ids):
    subnets.append(
        cdk_ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(
            scope=self,
            id=f"subnet{idx}",
            subnet_id=subnet_id
        )
    )
```

This will create a list of [ISubnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/ISubnet.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.ISubnet) objects, which can then be used with other methods like [SubnetSelection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/SubnetSelection.html), which can in turn be passed to some constructs. For example, [FargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateService.html) accepts an argument `vpc_subnets`, which can use the above list like this (ignored the other arguments):

```
FargateService(
    (...)
    vpc_subnets=cdk_ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=subnets)
)
```

What is the difference to Niranjan's answer? Well, seeing as AZ and RouteID are optional on `from_subnet_attributes()`, I don't know. I'll just leave this answer here because it has some additional links.

Comment: how did you manage to use SubnetSelection interface ?? When I am trying to use SubnetSelection interface, it is not visible. I get the compilation error -- Property 'SubnetSelection' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/sunnyarya/workspaces/aws-resource-provisioner/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/index")'

Comment: @sunnyarya in CDK's python implementation, `SubnetSelection` is a class that can be instantiated

Comment: In Typescript, create the SubnetSelection object by instantiating a normal object with subnets field in it. E.g. {subnets:[your_subnets]}

Comment: Fantastic, finally worked!! Was https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613777/1021819 also required?