# Issue with Subnet Selections

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an Application Load Balancer and I am unable to select specific subnets. It is a REQUIREMENT to select specific subnets because there are several of each type.

```
    # dmz_subnet_1 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_attributes(self,'DMZSubnetSelect1',availability_zone=region + 'a',route_table_id=vpc.pub_rt.ref,subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_1.ref)
    # dmz_subnet_2 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_attributes(self,'DMZSubnetSelect2',availability_zone=region + 'b',route_table_id=vpc.pub_rt.ref,subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_2.ref)

    # dmz_subnet_1 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self,'DMZSubnetSelect1',subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_1.ref)
    # dmz_subnet_2 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self,'DMZSubnetSelect2',subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_2.ref)

    # dmz_subnet_1 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self,'DMZSubnetSelect1',subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_1.logical_id)
    # dmz_subnet_2 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self,'DMZSubnetSelect2',subnet_id=vpc.epic_dmz_2.logical_id)        

    subnet_select = ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=[dmz_subnet_1, dmz_subnet_2])

    test_ext_elb = elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self,
        id='Test External ELB',
        http2_enabled=True,
        ip_address_type=elb.IpAddressType.IPV4,
        security_group=vpc.epic_prd_dmz_sg,
        vpc=vpc.vpc,
        internet_facing=True,
        load_balancer_name='testingexternalelb',
        vpc_subnets=subnet_select
    )
```

The 6 commented lines at the top are different variations I have tried. All result in this error when called in the elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 45, in <module>
    elb_stack = EpicElbStack(app, "epic-elb", env=cdk_env, vpc=vpc_stack, cache=cache_stack, core=core_stack, region=region)
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 66, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epic_cdk\epic_elb_stack.py", line 196, in __init__
    test_ext_elb = elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self,
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 66, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\aws_elasticloadbalancingv2\__init__.py", line 13673, in __init__
    jsii.create(ApplicationLoadBalancer, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\__init__.py", line 224, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 333, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "C:\repos\aws\epic-cdk\epiccdk\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 318, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: baseProps.vpc.selectSubnets is not a function
```

I found the example code from this answer: [AWS CDK subnet selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658249/aws-cdk-subnet-selections)

But for some reason, it isn't working for me. Maybe an update to CDK changed something?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this so its not left unanswered, i am sure OP has moved on by now.

I am making an assumption that the VPC you created cannot call the function selectSubnets.

For example when creating a VPC if you use the construct:

```
vpc = aws_ec2.cfnVPC(...)
```

The construct will NOT have the required selectSubnets function. If however you use:

```
vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(...)
```

It will.

This poses other issues as the `aws_ec2.Vpc(...)` construct creates other resources, such as a public and private subnet by default so there maybe more of an appropriate function to use.